# SDN4: Recent snapshot build broken

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Just started getting the following exception while starting the server:

```
Error creating bean with name 'myRepository': Invocation of init method failed;  nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/context/InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath
```

What changes could have caused this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to SDN4.  This bit here:  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the real issue is that you're missing a dependency or JAR in your runtime environment.

Comment: Which I think is likely due to some refactoring work on SDN4 / OGM in the snapshot build. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137728/sdn-4-inprocessserver-broken-in-snapshot-build

Comment: Can you update your m2 repo? mvn -U

Comment: I'm actually experiencing the exact same issue, even after blowing away my Gradle cache.  Is `InvalidPersistentPropertyPath` a part of the data commons library?

Comment: Found a workaround - see below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using Gradle and was experiencing the exact same issue.

`InvalidPersistentPropertyPath` seems to have been introduced in the latest SNAPSHOT build of `spring-data-commons` (1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT).  My project also includes Spring Data JPA which relies on a more stable version (1.11.0.M1).  Gradle did some conflict resolution and went with the M1 library, which does not have the new class and resulted in the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

For now, I am working around this by telling Gradle to ignore `spring-data-commons` as a transitive dependency of JPA so that the SNAPSHOT build being pulled in as a transitive dependency of SDN is used:

```
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:$springDataJpaVersion") {
  exclude group: "org.springframework.data", module: "spring-data-commons"
}
```

If you're using Gradle, you can check for conflicts using:

```
./gradlew <project>:dependencies
```

I think it will be worthwhile to check on the release schedules for each of these projects but for not this workaround is allowing our builds to continue.

Comment: Yes, changing to BUILD-SNAPSHOT is the right thing to do for now.  We'll endeavour to ensure the correct version in subsequent builds.

Comment: Thanks simonl. I’m using Maven with Spring Boot 1.3.0.M1 so I’ve posted my version of the fix below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Maven, with Spring Boot 1.3.0.M1, spring-data-neo4j 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and neo4j 2.2.2.

As simonl suggested overriding spring-data-commons 1.11.0.M1 with 1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT fixes the issue.

```
<!-- Fix ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentPropertyAccessor -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I remember having to do this in the past when working with newer versions of Neo4j with SDN 3, but haven't needed the spring-data-commons override with SDN 4, until now.